# R - BayesFactor: Creating a plot from a for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, plot, bayesian

I am new to R and am trying to create a plot based on the results from a for loop. I am using the BayesFactor package to find several Bayes factors

```
N <- seq (10, 500, by = 5)

for (i in 1:length(N)) {ttest.tstat(2.24, N[i], simple = TRUE}
```

Now I want to create a basic plot with N (on x-axis) and BayesFactors (on y-axis). How can I translate the resulting Bayes Factors from the for loop into a vector?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like:

```
N <- seq (10, 500, by = 5)
tstat_vec = sapply(N, ttest.stat, t = 2.24, simple = TRUE)
plot(N, tstat_vec)
```

should do the trick.

Or using `ggplot2`:

```
df = data.frame(N = N, tstat = tstat_vec)
ggplot(df) + geom_point(aes(x = N, y = tstat))
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way which I have found (insisting on the for loop) is

```
N <- seq(10, 500, by=5)
BF <- rep(0, 99)

for (i in 1:length(N)) {BF[i]=ttest.tstat(2.24, N[i], simple=TRUE)[[1]]}

plot.default(N,BF)
```

This also does the trick.